# Could I change the container's name of GitLab runner's job?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

I can use docker to build GitLab CI/CD now, and I know how to assign the name of 'gitlab-runner'. But when it builds projects, it will create lots of containers, some jobs consume lots of CPU but it's not easy to know the killer.

For example, the container name generated by gitlab-runner is 'runner-xkawnaf-project-*****' is it possible to add a prefix or any suggestion?

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS                  PORTS                    NAMES
7c2b650d29a5   439784af80f4                  "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second                            runner-xkawnaf-project-41-concurrent-0-0be8746bded98280-predefined-0
5be8cf16b490   gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   25 hours ago             Up 15 minutes                                    gitlab-runner
```

Comment: Do we have any answer on this, since I am looking for an answer to the same question?